# submit a list of questions to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to save the list of questions entered by the user into the database.

I am new with `reactJS` and I want to save the name and the list of all questions into the database when I click on VALIDATE.

For now I can save the name but not the list of questions

```
addQuestion = e => {
  this.setState({
     questions : [...this.state.questions, e.target.value]
   })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const newIntent = {
        name: this.state.name,
        questions: this.state.questions
    }
    this.props.addNewIntent(newIntent, this.props.history);
}

import axios from "axios";

export const addNewIntent = (newIntent, history) => async dispatch => {

    await axios.post("http://localhost:8081/intents", newIntent);
};
```

[my entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R2G0.png)

with this code, I can save the name to the database but not the list on questions

[my user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YMzH.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Soufyane! Please include your code in text format in the question instead of linking to external images, and include all relevant code in the question. E.g. what does the `this.props.addNewIntent` do?

Comment: i included my code into a code block, i dont really get what you mean

Comment: You link to an image of your backend code. It will be impossible for someone to help you if you don't show how `addNewIntent` is currently implemented.

Comment: do i have to screen my code and link it as image ?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect request from your browser to see if your intent is sent as expected ?

Comment: my intent name is sent coorrectly , i can see it in the database.. but the list of questions no.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved 
i added this map function

```
  onSubmit() {

    **var questions=this.state.questions.map((element) =>
      { return { content: element } })** 

    const newIntent = {
        name: this.state.name,
        questions: questions
    }

    this.props.addNewIntent(newIntent, this.props.history);
}
```